# Append multiple data to httpbody of URLRequest

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlrequest

I want to append another dictionary as a parameter to `httpBody` of `URLRequest`

Request Model:

```
struct RequestModel: Encodable {

    let body: Body
}

struct Body: Encodable {
    let name: String
    let score: String
    let favList: [String]
}
```

Api Request:

```
do {
            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: resourceURL)
            urlRequest.httpMethod = kHTTPMethodPOST
            urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(self.requestModel)

            let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in

                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                    httpResponse.statusCode == 200,
                    let jsonData = data else {
                        completion(.failure(.responseError))
                        return
                }


            }
            dataTask.resume()

        } catch {
         completion(.failure(.unknownError))
        }
```

Another dictionary: `airports`

```
var airports: [String: String] = ["YYZ": "Toronto Pearson", "DUB": "Dublin"]
```

trying to append `airports` dictionary parameter to `URLRequest` but can't append.

Appreciate your help and suggestion!

Thanks

Comment: What is the JSON you are trying to send?

Comment: Unrelated but the `URLRequest → NSURLRequest → NSMutableURLRequest → URLRequest` dance is pointless. `URLRequest` is mutable declared as `var`iable. And what is the purpose of `setProperty(true, forKey: ""`?

Comment: initially, I used URLRequest but we can't append data so made this conversion. Btw I updated with URLRequest. If you know the solution, please suggest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to append the `airports` dictionary to the request body, you may want to include it in the Request model itself.

I would suggest updating your `RequestModel` and make it `Encodable`.

And include your `airports` dict as a part of your `RequestModel`

Something like this

```
struct RequestModel: Encodable {

    let body: Body
    let airportsDict: [String:String]
}

struct Body: Encodable {
    let name: String
    let score: String
    let favList: [String]
}
```

This way your `httpBody` will have all the data you want to pass.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The usual syntax to `POST` JSON is

```
do { 
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: resourceURL)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postData = try JSONEncoder().encode(self.requestModel)
    urlRequest.httpBody = postData
    urlRequest.setValue("\(postData.count)", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Length")
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept")
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")

}
```